# ruby on rails custom setter help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, setter

sorry for my english,

I have a model named `Recipe` and Recipe has an attribute named `duration`

In my form, I have 2 dropdowns to get duration attribute

```
select_tag 'duration[hours]'
select_tag 'duration[minutes]'
```

I need the value of duration attribute like this format `hh:mm:ss`

I have tried with

```
def duration=(d)
  self.duration = "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00"
end
```

but that is not working

help please

Thk in advice!

Comment: when you say "not working", what does that mean? Is there an error message, or does the code just sit around all day refusing to get a job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With

```
def duration=(d)
  self.duration = "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00"
end
```

In your method you call yourself because it's the same method. You need change the attributes duration not the method

```
def duration=(d)
  write_attribute(:duration, "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00")
end
```

Comment: write_attribute has been deprecated for some time: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/write_attribute

Answer (score 4):

Here is the correct syntax that you were looking for:

In the view (recipes/_form.html.erb...)

```
select_tag 'duration[hours]'
select_tag 'duration[minutes]'
```

In the model (recipe.rb...)

```
def duration=(d)
  write_attribute(:duration, "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00")
end
```

For completeness, to override the getter

```
def duration
  read_attribute(:duration)
end
```

You can also use:

```
self[:duration] = "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00"
self[:duration]
```

But NOT:

```
self.duration = "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00"
self.duration
```

Going through self.name will call getter or setter functions (which you are attempting to override)

Answer (score 0):

Your form elements are named `hours` and `minutes` but your model is looking for `h` and `m` keys?

Is that really what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it

```
select_tag 'custom_duration[hours]'
select_tag 'custom_duration[minutes]'
```

I created a setter method with a diferent name than attribute to set my attribute

```
def custom_duration=(d)
  self.duration = "#{d[:hours]}:#{d[:minutes]}:00"
end
```

thk any way

Regards.